# Reveal div CSS3 animation

Tags: html, css

I want to do CSS3 animation like

```css
@keyframes ImageAnimation {
    0% 
    {
        width:100%;
        opacity:1;
    }
   100% 
    {
        width:0;
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.ImageAnimation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    animation: ImageAnimation 2s forwards;
}
.ImageAnimation img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ImageAnimation">
 <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" />
</div>
```

I am overlapping this div on another div which contain same image with some changes. I want to reveal below div with CSS3 animation, but I don't want to compress image while transition.

Comment: you dont want to compress the image? Do you want the image to slide instead of shrinking?

Comment: I want somethink like this.. https://jsfiddle.net/ypwuzqfk/1/

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more as in the fiddle shown there is only one div and in your case its saying that you are overlapping this div on another div. So you just want to hide this image/div and reveal the div below it and that also with animation right?

Comment: I have updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ypwuzqfk/3/

Comment: ok so what is the issue? the fiddle seesm to work. What is that you are expecting that should happen and is going wrong? Elaborate you problem and the expected behavior then only i will be able to help.

Comment: Ya I have achieve this but the problem is I want same transition effect from left to right.

Comment: ok so you want the same thing to happen when the imag reappears right i.e the transition from left to right is sudden right now but you want it to be similar to that from right to left?

Comment: yes If I change left:0 to right:0 then its look like sliding effect. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits your requirements but you just have to overlap your two images (with overlapping divs or background-image) and set your animation on the front-div as you can see [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn4qq42n/).

I set the background-image with:

```
.bg{
height: 400px;
background-image: url(images/the_image.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```